# exclude a globally included js in a nuxt.js page

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have included a script that is used globally in `nuxt.config.js`

But after a while there is 1 page that have no use of that script, and I want to exclude it for that page only

Is there a way to do it? or I need to update my pages to include the script locally, instead of include it globally?